# Resultset's getObject() method - how to use it properly?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I make a database query and store `Account` objects in the `ResultSet`. Here is the code:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = queryDatabase();
    int i=0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        Account account= rs.getObject(i, Account); //ERROR
        accounts.add(account);
        i++;
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

This code returns 3 objects and stores them in the rs. Then I want to get those objects in the `ResultSet` and put them into an `ArrayList` as you see in the code. But it gives an error in the specified line saying that `;` expected. How can I use `getObject` method properly?

Comment: Why are there double parentheses next to `getObject`: `((` and `))`?

Comment: It's telling you that you have a *syntax error*. Like, too many parenthesis, and a Type where is doesn't belong, for example.

Comment: well, sorry about parantheses i fixed them

Comment: @BrianRoach sadly, my answer can't be covered in comments only =\

Comment: is this way question is downvoted or is it a too easy question to ask? If i know the reason i will try to fix while asking questions in the future

Comment: @iceface the problem is that you don't understand how JDBC works, so the first thing to do would be reviewing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ResultSet.getObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) (and the other `getXxx` methods) will retrieve the data from the current row of the `ResultSet` and starts in index 1. You have set your `i` variable with 0 value.

Just change this

```
int i=0;
```

To

```
int i=1;
```

Also, `getObject` needs a single param, but you're incorrectly sending two:

```
Account account= rs.getObject(i, Account);
```

Probably you were trying to use [`ResultSet#getObject(int, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int,%20java.lang.Class%29) (available from Java 7), but you have to take into account that your `Account` class can't be *magically* converted from a database column to an instance of this object.

Looks like it would be better to review [JDBC trial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) first, then retry to solve your problem.

Here's another good source to review: [Using Customized Type Mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html)

Comment: i tried it, and also changed the erroneus line to Account account= rs.getObject(i, Account.class); now no syntax errors but it returns null, i will debug and edit the question, thanks by the way

Comment: that makes sense, i found a way to do it thanks. When we make String s=rs.getString(0); it gives no error so i thought if i do the same for Account object, that would be ok but it does not

Comment: but about your answer, getObject method can also take two parameters it is not wrong

Comment: iceface, your database doesn't contain instances of your Account class, unless you've put them there as Blobs, in which case you're still using the API wrongly. Take Luigi's advice and review JDBC and its tutorials.

Comment: Does anyone know why ResultSet.getObject(int i) starts counting columns from 1 and not 0 (as any array) ?

Answer (score 1):

Our object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
...
class Account implements Serializable{
   public String data;
}
```

How to get our object from bd:

```
while (rs.next()) {
        Object accountJustObject = rs.getObject(i); 
        Account account = (Account)accountJustObject;
        accounts.add(account);
        i++;
}
```

How to save our object:

```
public void InsertAccount(int id, Account newaccount){
 reparedStatement insertNew = conn.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO root(id,account) VALUES (?,?)";
   insertNew.setInt(1, id);             //INT   field type
   insertNew.setObject(2, newaccount);  //OTHER field type
   insertNew.executeUpdate();  
 )
}
```

Tested under H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

Object Variables, are:

- only REFERENCES to a space in memory.
- any REFERENCE uses memory (just a little bit)
- the way to get/use any object of a specific Type of Class from one reference is by simple Typecasting it.